# How can I find all the plot themes for a given function?

Tags: plotting, undocumented, plot-themes

[Plot themes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html) are useful little things that ease the pain of manually styling Mathematica graphics. I have a few favorites, `"Web"`, `"Scientific"`, etc. but when I'm trying our new graphics styling sometimes I want to play with various ones.

So how can I find all the plot themes for, say, `Plot`?

Answer (score 2):

We'll start by extracting all the plot themes:

```
allPlotThemes =
  GroupBy[
   Cases[
    System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme // DownValues // Keys,
    HoldPattern[
      System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme[___?(Not@*StringQ), 
       things__String, ___?(Not@*StringQ)]
      ] :>
     With[{ll = {things}},
      If[Length@ll == 2,
       Rule @@ Reverse[ll],
       All -> ll[[1]]
       ]
      ],
    Infinity
    ],
   First -> Last,
   Sort@*DeleteDuplicates
   ];
```

Then we'll write a function that'll find the distinct styles for a function:

```
fullThemes[sym_] :=
  Select[
   Sort@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Values@allPlotThemes,
   With[{main = Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, sym]},
    Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[#, sym] =!= main &
    ]
   ];
```

And applying that to `Plot`:

```
fullThemes[Plot]

{"AGU", "AHA", "AmericanGeophysicalUnion", \
"AmericanHeartAssociation", "AnnualReviews", "AR", "ASPET", \
"BioMedCentral", "BlackBackground", "BlackDefaultAxes", "BMC", \
"BoldLabel", "BoldLabels", "Business", "BusinessPresentation", \
"CellPress", "Classic", "ClassicColor", "ClassicColors", \
"ClassicComponent", "Coarse", "ColorStyle", "Correspondence", "CP", \
"Dashboard", "DashedLines", "Detailed", "DoubleAxis", "Elsevier", \
"Fine", "Frame", "FrameAxes", "FrameAxis", "FrameGrid", "Full", \
"FullAxes", "FullAxesGrid", "Grid", "Grids", "HeavyLines", \
"HeightGrid", "HeightGridBlack", "Icon", "IEEE", \
"IEEEComputerSociety", "IEEECS", "Inline", \
"InstituteOfElectricalAndElectronicsEngineers", "InterResearch", \
"IR", "ItalicLabel", "ItalicLabels", "JournalArticle", "LabelStyle", \
"Large", "LargeLabel", "LargeLabels", "LargeLabelsWhite", \
"LargeLabelWhite", "LargePadding", "Legend", "LegendPlaceholder", \
"LegendPlaceholders", "Legends", "Marketing", "MarketingColor", \
"MarketingPresentation", "Medium", "Minimal", "MinimalAxes", \
"MinimalAxis", "MinimalComponent", "MobileApp", "Monochrome", \
"NaturePublishingGroup", "NoAxes", "NoPadding", "Notepad", "NPG", \
"PLoS", "PLoS3", "Poster", "Presentation", "PublicLibraryOfScience", \
"PublicLibraryOfScienceThreeColumnLayout", "Sans", "SB", \
"Scientific", "ScientificJournal", "Serif", "SimpleEndTicks", \
"SimpleGrid", "SimpleTicks", "SingleAxis", "SizeScale", "SJ", \
"Small", "SmallLabel", "SmallLabels", "SolidGrid", "SolidGridDark", \
"SolidGridDarkBlack", "Sparkline", "SpringerBooks", \
"SpringerJournals", "Square", "StylesheetStyle", "Tall", \
"TaylorFrancis", "TechnicalPresentation", "Test", "TF", "ThickLine", \
"ThickLines", "ThinLine", "ThinLines", "Thumbnail", "Tiny", \
"TrueScale", "Version9", "Web", "WebDetailed", "WhiteDefaultAxes", \
"Wide", "WolframAlpha", "WSM", "WSMBlack", "WSMBlackDark", \
"WSMBlackFill", "WSMBlackFillStripe", "WSMBlackStripe", "WSMDark", \
"WSMFill", "WSMFillStripe", "WSMPastel", "WSMPastelDark", \
"WSMPastelFill", "WSMPastelFillStripe", "WSMPastelStripe", \
"WSMStripe", "WSMVibrant", "WSMVibrantDark", "WSMVibrantFill", \
"WSMVibrantFillStripe", "WSMVibrantStripe"}
```

And we see lots of fun stuff. Some publisher specific styles, something for a `"MobileApp"`, should WL ever be a truly viable framework for that. And then all sorts of `"WSM"` styles (which I assume are for Wolfram System Modeler).

Trying some of these on at random:

[image: themeses]

It looks like most are pretty minor variants, but the WSM styles are all pretty cool, actually.

Comment: A caveat for other users: I just tried this (great!) function (`fullThemes[Plot]`) in a fresh kernel, and the first execution returned an empty list. This is probably because some internals had not yet been loaded. Further evaluations worked as expected. Thanks @b3m2a1! (+1)